# How to make the loop with json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make loop with json data that show in html title, link, description of some addvertisment. Here you have json template with two adds, in practice my json have 10-20 id. What Im doing wrong with below code?

JSON in Variable

```
var text = '{  
"wynik":{  
  "wynikOk":true,
  "kodWykonania":0,
  "kodBledu":null,
  "komunikat":null,
  "dodatkoweInfo":null,
  "userData":null
},
"czasWykonania":null,
"addvertisments":[  
  {  
     "id":721,
     "status":1,
     "title":"Tester",
     "link":"#",
     "description":"Aliquam quis erat vitae lectus blandit auctor. Cras placerat sapien a nibh ultricies viverra. Duis nulla massa, pulvinar et lacinia vitae, congue non dolor. Sed pellentesque ut augue eu condimentum. Cras elit nisi, rutrum eu enim at, varius consectetur leo. Maecenas a bibendum nibh, sed sagittis velit. Donec vehicula purus vel orci pretium auctor. Mauris vestibulum suscipit nulla mollis ornare.",
     "dtwo":"2016/03/02",
     "idAddType":{  
        "id":2,
        "name":"Testers"
     },
     "regions":[  
        {  
           "id":12,
           "name":"region_1"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "id":74,
     "status":1,
     "title":"Tester 2",
     "link":"#",
     "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in risus eu velit laoreet vehicula. Aliquam eleifend vitae velit in suscipit. Aenean elementum, sapien sed consectetur aliquet, massa sem fringilla massa, non vulputate velit erat efficitur nibh. Cras quis libero eu lacus interdum hendrerit nec sed eros. Aliquam imperdiet rutrum ipsum a finibus. Phasellus dolor nunc, convallis sit amet nulla ut, sollicitudin ultricies magna. Fusce id nunc felis. Etiam faucibus finibus semper. Fusce semper quam nec tellus efficitur, vel mattis magna finibus. Sed felis neque, aliquam sed lectus eget, ultricies pretium libero. Duis ut posuere nisi.",
     "dtwo":"2016/02/12",
     "idAddType":{  
        "id":3,
        "name":"Prorgrammers"
     },
     "regions":[  
        {  
           "id":15,
           "name":"region_2"
        }
     ]
  },




 ]
}';
```

My Function

```
myFunction(text);


function myFunction(arr) {
var out = "";
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += '<li><div><span>' + arr[i].title + '</span></div><div><p>' + arr[i].description + '</p><div><a  href=' + arr[i].link + '>apply</a></div></li>';
}
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qut10dxw/

Comment: title, link, description from json with each adds

Comment: Is there any way to put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qut10dxw/

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it first with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and take only the array as parameter for the function.

```js
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<li><div><span>' + arr[i].title + '</span></div><div><p>' + arr[i].description + '</p><div><a  href=' + arr[i].link + '>apply</a></div></li>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

var text = '{ "wynik": { "wynikOk": true, "kodWykonania": 0, "kodBledu": null, "komunikat": null, "dodatkoweInfo": null, "userData": null }, "czasWykonania": null, "addvertisments": [{ "id": 721, "status": 1, "title": "Tester", "link": "#", "description": "Aliquam quis erat vitae lectus blandit auctor. Cras placerat sapien a nibh ultricies viverra. Duis nulla massa, pulvinar et lacinia vitae, congue non dolor. Sed pellentesque ut augue eu condimentum. Cras elit nisi, rutrum eu enim at, varius consectetur leo. Maecenas a bibendum nibh, sed sagittis velit. Donec vehicula purus vel orci pretium auctor. Mauris vestibulum suscipit nulla mollis ornare.", "dtwo": "2016/03/02", "idAddType": { "id": 2, "name": "Testers" }, "regions": [{ "id": 12, "name": "region_1" }] }, { "id": 74, "status": 1, "title": "Tester 2", "link": "#", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in risus eu velit laoreet vehicula. Aliquam eleifend vitae velit in suscipit. Aenean elementum, sapien sed consectetur aliquet, massa sem fringilla massa, non vulputate velit erat efficitur nibh. Cras quis libero eu lacus interdum hendrerit nec sed eros. Aliquam imperdiet rutrum ipsum a finibus. Phasellus dolor nunc, convallis sit amet nulla ut, sollicitudin ultricies magna. Fusce id nunc felis. Etiam faucibus finibus semper. Fusce semper quam nec tellus efficitur, vel mattis magna finibus. Sed felis neque, aliquam sed lectus eget, ultricies pretium libero. Duis ut posuere nisi.", "dtwo": "2016/02/12", "idAddType": { "id": 3, "name": "Prorgrammers" }, "regions": [{ "id": 15, "name": "region_2" }] }] }';
myFunction(JSON.parse(text).addvertisments);
```

```html
<div id="id01"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call your function with

```
text['addvertisments']
```

then everything should be OK.

You can replace

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
```

with

```
for (var i in arr){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your json string is incorrect: 
Try this string:

```
var text = "{
    "wynik": {
        "wynikOk": true,
        "kodWykonania": 0,
        "kodBledu": null,
        "komunikat": null,
        "dodatkoweInfo": null,
        "userData": null
    },
    "czasWykonania": null,
    "addvertisments": [{
        "id": 721,
        "status": 1,
        "title": "Tester",
        "link": "#",
        "description": "Aliquam quis erat vitae lectus blandit auctor. Cras placerat sapien a nibh ultricies viverra. Duis nulla massa, pulvinar et lacinia vitae, congue non dolor. Sed pellentesque ut augue eu condimentum. Cras elit nisi, rutrum eu enim at, varius consectetur leo. Maecenas a bibendum nibh, sed sagittis velit. Donec vehicula purus vel orci pretium auctor. Mauris vestibulum suscipit nulla mollis ornare.",
        "dtwo": "2016/03/02",
        "idAddType": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Testers"
        },
        "regions": [{
            "id": 12,
            "name": "region_1"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 74,
        "status": 1,
        "title": "Tester 2",
        "link": "#",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in risus eu velit laoreet vehicula. Aliquam eleifend vitae velit in suscipit. Aenean elementum, sapien sed consectetur aliquet, massa sem fringilla massa, non vulputate velit erat efficitur nibh. Cras quis libero eu lacus interdum hendrerit nec sed eros. Aliquam imperdiet rutrum ipsum a finibus. Phasellus dolor nunc, convallis sit amet nulla ut, sollicitudin ultricies magna. Fusce id nunc felis. Etiam faucibus finibus semper. Fusce semper quam nec tellus efficitur, vel mattis magna finibus. Sed felis neque, aliquam sed lectus eget, ultricies pretium libero. Duis ut posuere nisi.",
        "dtwo": "2016/02/12",
        "idAddType": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Prorgrammers"
        },
        "regions": [{
            "id": 15,
            "name": "region_2"
        }]
    }]

}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing parse your JSON, because the `text` variable is just a string. And you also must get the `addvertisments` property of your JSON like so:

```
function myFunction(text) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(text).addvertisments;
    var out = "";
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<li><div><span>' + arr[i].title + '</span></div><div><p>' + arr[i].description + '</p><div><a  href=' + arr[i].link + '>apply</a></div></li>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```